# Why is the color space of the CV::Mat image wrong (GBR instead of RGB or BGR)?

Tags: c++, opencv, pybind11

I have a module in Python which sends an RGB to C++ and there its consumed. The image however, has wrong colorspace, regardless of what I do. That is I tried to convert it to `RGB`, assuming its still in BGR (although in python its deliberately converted into RGB by  doing :`return img[:,:,::-1]` and visualize the image using matplotlib.) and vice versa, they look the same!

This is shown below:

Original image:

[image]

This is the output of the image without any tampering

[image]

This is the output when the I use colorspace conversion from BGR2RGB:

```cpp
cv::Mat img2;
cv::cvtColor(img, img2, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
cv::imshow(title + " type:" + image_type, img2);
```

[image]

And this is what I get when I try to convert as a RGB2BGR:

```cpp
cv::Mat img2;
cv::cvtColor(img, img2, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);
cv::imshow(title + " type:" + image_type, img2);
```

[image]

And as you can see the last two are identical. So I tried to manually change the channels and see if I can get this to work. The code snippet:

```cpp
cv::Mat img2;
cv::cvtColor(img, img2, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);
//cv::cvtColor(img, img2, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++) {
        img2.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[0];
        img2.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[1];
        img2.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[2];
    }
}

cv::imshow(title + " type:" + image_type, img2);
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Clearly this is the RGB and everything looks good and it seems the image was in GBR format! I have no idea what is causing this.

Also I noticed, I must do a conversion, or else the following for loops will give me memory access violations! which is strange to me! Changing the `BGR2RGB` or `RGB2BGR` in the `cvtColor` doesn't have any effect and they act the same.

I would also like to know if there is a better way for getting this into the right colorspace, something that doesn't require a for loop like the one I wrote and uses hardware acceleration? Since this operation needs to be fast but using the current solution that I have is not good at all.

### Edit

By the way this is the Python function I was calling in my C++:

```py
def detect_and_align_all(pil_img):
    """gets the input image, and returns all the faces aligned as a list of rgb images 
    """
    bboxes, landmarks = detect_faces(pil_img)
    # convert to ndarray and then make rgb to bgr
    cv_img = np.array(pil_img)[:, :, ::-1].copy()
    img_list = []
    for landmark in landmarks:
        img = align_face(cv_img, landmark)
        img_list.append(img[:, :, ::-1])

    return img_list
```

and `align_face` ultimately calls this:

```py
return cv2.warpAffine(cv_img, tfm, (crop_size[0], crop_size[1]))
```

### Update 1

These are the snippets (taken from here) that I use to send the image from c++ to python using Pybind11:

```cpp
py::dtype determine_np_dtype(int depth)
{
    switch (depth) 
    {
    case CV_8U: return py::dtype::of<uint8_t>();
    case CV_8S: return py::dtype::of<int8_t>();
    case CV_16U: return py::dtype::of<uint16_t>();
    case CV_16S: return py::dtype::of<int16_t>();
    case CV_32S: return py::dtype::of<int32_t>();
    case CV_32F: return py::dtype::of<float>();
    case CV_64F: return py::dtype::of<double>();
    default:
        throw std::invalid_argument("Unsupported data type.");
    }
}

std::vector<std::size_t> determine_shape(cv::Mat& m)
{
    if (m.channels() == 1) {
        return {
            static_cast<size_t>(m.rows)
            , static_cast<size_t>(m.cols)
        };
    }

    return {
        static_cast<size_t>(m.rows)
        , static_cast<size_t>(m.cols)
        , static_cast<size_t>(m.channels())
    };
}

py::capsule make_capsule(cv::Mat& m)
{
    return py::capsule(new cv::Mat(m)
        , [](void* v) { delete reinterpret_cast<cv::Mat*>(v); }
    );
}

py::array mat_to_nparray(cv::Mat& m)
{
    if (!m.isContinuous()) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Only continuous Mats supported.");
    }

    return py::array(determine_np_dtype(m.depth())
        , determine_shape(m)
        , m.data
        , make_capsule(m));
}
```

and used like this :

```cpp
py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
auto module = py::module::import("MyPackage.align_faces");
auto aligner = module.attr("align_all");
auto pil_converter = module.attr("cv_to_pil");

auto img = cv::imread("image1.jpg");
auto img_pil = pilConvertor(mat_to_nparray(img));
auto img_face_list = aligner(img_pil);
```

### Update 2

Thanks to @DanMasek in the comments, by storing the copy of images on the python side, just before sending them back to C++, the above issue is solved. However, as Ext3h pointed out in the comments, there is an artifact in the image as well which is not gone even after the latest change.

I saved two images (bgr mode) both in Python and C++ using `imwrite`, the artifact that shows up here, doesn't show up in these images. however, there is a slight difference between the two images. the cpp image is a bit zoomed in compared to the python version (they both use the very same function (in fact c++ calls the very same python module for this)). and the Python version is also bigger in size:

cpp image(size: 5,492 bytes):

[image]

Python image(size: (5,587 bytes)

[image]

What's the issue here? the codes that I used, does not alter the strides/offsets of any kind, in fact) then what's stemming this issue?

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your manual attempt, inside the for when you read `[2]` in your third line, you find it equal to `[0]` due to the first line. you should use a temporary variable to hold the old `[2]` value.

Comment: @bracco23 Thanks but if you look closely you can see that it reads from `img` and writes into `img2` so its not overwritten.

Comment: Yeah, my fault, you're right.

Comment: Are you certain you did not introduce an unintended off-by-one somewhere? There is just one byte offset between `RGB` and accidentally interpreting it as `GBR`, the later then also including alignment issues in OpenCV. Off by more than one actually, as you also got that fishy artifact showing to the right of the face. Meaning you are completely misaligned.

Comment: How do you send the image from Python? As raw RGB or encoded as JPEG or PNG? Have you tried sending a pure red image, then a pure blue one?

Comment: @Ext3h : its very possible that on the c++ side, when I am sending the image, something happens. on python, its verified and everything works 100% fine. I use Pybind11 and used (this link)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60949451/how-to-send-a-cvmat-to-python-over-shared-memory] to send the image from c++ to python. just copied and pasted it and it seems working except this!

Comment: @MarkSetchell please kindly see my previous comment. I used the snippet here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60949451/how-to-send-a-cvmat-to-python-over-shared-memory

Comment: I updated the question with the codes that I use to send the image from c++ to python

Comment: What are the sizes of input and output images? The issue might be related to stride. See this link: https://medium.com/@oleg.shipitko/what-does-stride-mean-in-image-processing-bba158a72bcd

Comment: @PiotrSiekański : the input is 168x300 (rows,cols) and output is 112x112. Thanks a lot i'll look at it

Comment: What if you change `img_list.append(img[:, :, ::-1])` to append a copy of that? I recall the main OpenCV bindings don't like array views with reversed indices like this, maybe it's a problem for pybind (or that code I wrote in my answer didn't account for such case)?

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks a lot :) I did as you said, and surprisingly its fine now! I mean, there is no need for that loop, and doing `cv::cvtColor(img, img2, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);` just prints the correct image!

Comment: I'd greatly apprecaite it if you could post this as answer and explain a bit what has gone wrong here?

Comment: Concerning the artifact in the image, its still present and I updated the question regarding this. the difference is tiny, but it exists, while it shouldnt exist imho. I did not use any kind of offsets/strides in the cpp code as you can see. so whats stemming this issue? should I create another question for this? or is it ok to continue this here?

Comment: Regarding my earlier suggestion -- numpy arrays are more flexible in regarding to indexing compared to `cv::Mat`. For example `[:, :, ::-1]` simply tells numpy to access the last dimension in reverse order, but OpenCV's `Mat` can't do that. When I have time for it, I'll review the answer you took inspiration from to add some checks to detect such incompatibilities and investigate this problem deeper.  Anyway, by making a copy, you reset all this indexing "weirdness" -- it means "read the data in the strange order, but write it in normal order".

Comment: The zoomed in difference between those two images seems like what `warpAffine` would do... Maybe in one scenario you're not actually storing the result of the transformation? Maybe turn that into a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219301/discussion-between-dan-masek-and-rika).