# How to convert raw pointers to lightweight python datatype using pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes, wrapper, pybind11

Consider this little pybind11 wrapper + test:

**setup.py**

```
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension
from pybind11.setup_helpers import build_ext
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="wrapper",
    ext_modules=[Pybind11Extension("wrapper", ["wrapper.cpp"])],
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
)
```

**wrapper.cpp**

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <vector>

namespace py = pybind11;

struct Mesh2d {
public:
  Mesh2d(int numVerts, int numTris)
      : numVertices(numVerts), numTriangles(numTris) {
    vertices = new float[numVerts * 2];
    indices = new int[numTris * 3];
  }

  ~Mesh2d() {
    delete vertices;
    delete indices;
  }

  void makeVertex(int i, float x, float y) {
    vertices[i * 2 + 0] = x;
    vertices[i * 2 + 1] = y;
  }

  void makeTriangle(int i, int a, int b, int c) {
    indices[i * 3 + 0] = a;
    indices[i * 3 + 1] = b;
    indices[i * 3 + 2] = c;
  }

  float *vertices;
  int *indices;
  int numVertices;
  int numTriangles;
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(wrapper, m) {
  m.doc() = "mcve";
  py::class_<Mesh2d>(m, "Mesh2d")
      .def(py::init<int, int>())
      .def("make_vertex", &Mesh2d::makeVertex)
      .def("make_triangle", &Mesh2d::makeTriangle)
      .def_readonly("vertices", &Mesh2d::vertices)
      .def_readonly("indices", &Mesh2d::indices);
}
```

**test.py**

```
from wrapper import Mesh2d

def test():
    m = Mesh2d(3, 1)
    m.make_vertex(0, -1.0, -1.0)
    m.make_vertex(1, 1.0, -1.0)
    m.make_vertex(2, 0.0, 1.0)
    m.make_triangle(0, 0, 1, 2)
    print(m.vertices.__class__)
    print(m.indices.__class__)

test()
```

**Question**

Right now because I'm not doing anything special to neither vertices nor indices the `__class__` I'm getting in python land is `<class 'float'>` and `<class 'int'>` respectively. What'd be the proper pybind11 way to convert these raw pointers to some suitable object such as:

```
array.array("f", vertices)
array.array("I", indices)

(ctypes.c_float * 6)(*vertices)
(ctypes.c_uint * 3)(*indices)

memoryview(struct.pack("6f", *vertices))
memoryview(struct.pack("3I", *indices))

struct.pack("6f", *vertices)
struct.pack("3I", *indices)
```

My end goal here would be being able to generate really complex heavy data on c++ side (heavy data that will be modified in realtime). So having little overhead on the wrapper (ideally without any unnecesary copy to python data structures, just giving the raw pointer).

**Reference**

https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/functions.html#return-value-policies

Comment: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html# -- the memory view approach at the bottom is probably the lightest. Or turn them into full numpy arrays like i've done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60949451/how-to-send-a-cvmat-to-python-over-shared-memory/60959732#60959732) for OpenCV Mats.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not mistaken, you should be able to use a `numpy` array view of the memory for pretty cheap (if not almost no overhead). Here's a full example.

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <vector>

namespace py = pybind11;

struct Mesh2d {
public:
  Mesh2d(int numVerts, int numTris)
      : numVertices(numVerts), numTriangles(numTris) {
    vertices = new float[numVerts * 2];
    indices = new int[numTris * 3];

    // these constructors are just views of the memory and will not copy the data
    // (nor take ownership of the pointer)
    // You could also make these shapes {numVerts, 2} and {numTris, 3} or whatever else is helpful to you.
    pyVertices = py::array_t<float>({numVerts * 2}, vertices);
    pyIndices = py::array_t<int>({numTris * 3}, indices);
  }

  ~Mesh2d() {
    delete vertices;
    delete indices;
  }

  void makeVertex(int i, float x, float y) {
    vertices[i * 2 + 0] = x;
    vertices[i * 2 + 1] = y;
  }

  void makeTriangle(int i, int a, int b, int c) {
    indices[i * 3 + 0] = a;
    indices[i * 3 + 1] = b;
    indices[i * 3 + 2] = c;
  }

  float *vertices;
  int *indices;
  py::array_t<float> pyVertices;
  py::array_t<int> pyIndices;
  int numVertices;
  int numTriangles;
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(wrapper, m) {
  m.doc() = "mcve";
  py::class_<Mesh2d>(m, "Mesh2d")
      .def(py::init<int, int>())
      .def("make_vertex", &Mesh2d::makeVertex)
      .def("make_triangle", &Mesh2d::makeTriangle)
      .def_readonly("vertices", &Mesh2d::pyVertices)
      .def_readonly("indices", &Mesh2d::pyIndices);
}
```

The constructor being used for `py::array_t` is [here](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/include/pybind11/numpy.h#L907).
I would also point you to [xtensor](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor) if you're looking for something numpy like in C++.