# Python API to C++ - return pointer to object instead of full object

Tags: python, c++, api, opencv

I created a python module to call some c++ functions of my library.
It use opencv to manipulate some matrix.

My python code

```
image = "zebre_1080p.png"
intput_image = cv2.resize(image, (int(cols - cols % ratio), int(rows - rows % ratio)))

output_image = image

cv2.imshow('input',intput_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

test = py_module.testProcess(input_image, output_image) //increase the resolution of the input image

cv2.imshow('output',output_image)  // same as image
cv2.waitKey(0)


cv2.imshow('output',test) // input_image with new resolution
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

My C++ code

```
static PyObject* testProcess(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {

PyArrayObject *input, *output;
if ( ! PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OO", &input, &output) ) return NULL; 

cv::Mat in = cv::Mat(cv::Size(in_dims[0], in_dims[1]), CV_8UC3, PyArray_DATA(input));
cv::Mat out = cv::Mat(cv::Size(out_dims[0], out_dims[1]), CV_8UC3);

in ret = Process(in, out);
    if(ret < 0){
        printf("Erreur Process : %x\n", ret);
        return NULL;
    }

npy_intp dimens[] = {out.rows, out.cols};
PyObject* obj = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(out.dims, dimens, NPY_UINT8, out.data);

return obj;
```

So this solution works but I want to return the same value as my C++ function and like the c++ function return the out matrix in output_image object.
Like that :

```
ret = py_module.testModule(input_image, output_image) //increase the resolution of the input image

cv2.imshow('output',output_image)  // intput_image with new resolution
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I don't know if it is possible, maybe with :

```
Py_BuildValue("O", obj);
```

or something else ?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you're using C++, have you considered some higher level way of interfacing with Python? With pybind11 this should be quite easy, I show how to go from C++ to Python in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60949451/how-to-send-a-cvmat-to-python-over-shared-memory/60959732#60959732). | Otherwise, have a look at [this part](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp) of OpenCV (support code for the bindings generator), and find how they marshall Mats to numpy arrays using low level API.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to do it like that :

```
static PyObject* testProcess(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {

    _import_array();
    PyArrayObject *input, *output;
    if ( ! PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OO", &input, &output) ) return NULL;
     
    npy_intp* in_shape = PyArray_SHAPE(input);
    npy_intp* out_shape = PyArray_SHAPE(output);

    cv::Mat in =    cv::Mat(in_shape[0], in_shape[1], CV_8UC3, PyArray_DATA(input));
    cv::Mat out =   cv::Mat(out_shape[0], out_shape[1], CV_8UC3, PyArray_DATA(output));

    int ret = Process(in, out);
    if(ret < 0){
        printf("Erreur Process : %x\n", ret);
        return NULL;
    }

    PyArrayObject *obj = (PyArrayObject *)PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(out.channels(), out_shape, PyArray_TYPE(output), out.data);
    
    PyArray_MoveInto(output, obj);
    
    return PyLong_FromLong( 0 );
}
```

My python script :

```
def main():
    ratio = 2

    image = "zebre.png"

    #Read image
    orgHRImage = cv2.imread(image)
    
    cols, rows, dim = orgHRImage.shape
    #crop to %2
    orgHRImage = cv2.resize(orgHRImage, (int(cols - cols % ratio), int(rows - rows % ratio)))

    #downscale image
    downSize = (int(cols/ratio), int(rows/ratio))
    downScaledImage = cv2.resize(orgHRImage, downSize)

    #create empty output image 
    output = np.zeros(orgHRImage.shape, orgHRImage.dtype)

    #cv2.imshow('downScaledImage',downScaledImage)
    #cv2.waitKey(0)

    #cv2.imshow('output',output)
    #cv2.waitKey(0)

    py_module.testProcess(downScaledImage, output)

    #cv2.imshow('output',output)
    #cv2.waitKey(0)
```

So I create one input matrix (cv::Mat in) with the informations of &input (which is a image) and one output matrix (cv::Mat out) with the informations of &output (which was initialized at zeros in my python script.
I call the Process function to fill my output matrix.

I create a new PyArrayObject with the same properties of &output and with the fresh data of the matrix out.

I move the pointer to the new object to my old output pointer to have the new object.

I was able to see the picture resized its size divided by 2, next a black image and at the end the resized image from output.