# Convert Numpy array in python to C++ mat (opencv) using ctypes

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv

I have to create a (openCV) image processing function in C++ and have to call that function from python using ctypes.

so how can i pass a numpy array as an input to c++ function, than convert that array to Mat(opencv) in c++ and do the operations in c++ and return that Mat back to python script.

`python file`

```
import numpy
import cypes

libmatmult = ctypes.CDLL("./cpp_function.so")

def opencv_mat(a,b):
    # inits for cpp multiplications    
    ND_POINTER_1 = numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=numpy.float64, 
                                        ndim=2,
                                        flags="C")
    ND_POINTER_2 = numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=numpy.float64, 
                                        ndim=2,
                                        flags="C")
    libmatmult.opencv_dot.argtypes = [ND_POINTER_1, ND_POINTER_2, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_size_t]
    libmatmult.opencv_dot.restype = None #Needed numpy array
    np_array = libmatmult.opencv_dot(a, b, *a.shape, *b.shape , a.shape[0] * a.shape[1])
    return np_array

opencv_mat(numpy.random.uniform(1,255,(5,5)), numpy.random.uniform(1,255,(5,5)))
```

`C++ file`

Compile using :`g++ -shared -fPIC cpp_function.cpp -o cpp_function.so -I /usr/include/opencv4/ -L /usr/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

extern "C" {

    void opencv_dot(...){
        // 1) convert to np to cv::mat
        // 2) do any operations
        // 3) convert mat back to numpy compatible format
        // 4) return to python file
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have an ndarray e.g. `a`, You can pass the image data pointer (`a.ctypes.data`), together with the width, height and strides to the c++ side. Then construct a `cv::Mat` from an existing data pointer - without any copy (one of the `cv::Mat` ctors support it). Since it is using the ndarray memory as is, there's also no need to copy back.

Comment: look at Cython. it's giving you easy mapping between C/C++ world and numpy arrays.

Comment: If the use of ctypes is not a strong requirement (unless this is an assignment, not sure why it would be), I'd side to use pybind11 to write a binary Python module. It provides support for numpy arrays, you just need to create a `Mat` header reusing the underlying buffer this exposes. If you can reuse the input buffer as output, you may even avoid steps 3 and 4 above. I have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60959732/3962537) showing the opposite direction (C++ to Python), but a little research should yield existing solutions for Python to C++ as well.